# Jhipster - Change Title of the page

Tags: jhipster

In Jhipster, I am not able to change the title of the page. Whenever I change the title in index.html, the title automatically changes to the default title. (maybe because of JS). Kindly help...!

Comment: Have you checked pageTitle in your routes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer the below code to change title of the pages based on routes by **pageTitle**.

```
export const userMgmtRoute: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'user-management',
        component: UserMgmtComponent,
        resolve: {
            'pagingParams': UserResolvePagingParams
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'userManagement.home.title'
        }
    },
    {
        path: 'user-management/:login',
        component: UserMgmtDetailComponent,
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'userManagement.home.title'
        }
    }
];
```

Reference : https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management.route.ts

Comment: Yes, the problem was in the route.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I needed to change the constant HOME_ROUTE in:

src/main/webapp/home/home.route.ts

It has a pageTitle attribute which needs to be changed accordingly. I guess Jhipster does this for security purposes.

Thanks a lot guys.